# OpenCV specific object detection

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, kinect

After doing some research and reading information about OpenCV object detection, I am still not sure on how can I detect a stick in a video frame. What would be the best way so i can detect even if the user moves it around. I'll be using the stick as a sword and make a lightsaber out of it. Any points on where I can start? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The go-to answer for this would usually be the Hough line transform. The Hough transform is designed to find straight lines (or other contours) in the scene, and OpenCV can parameterize these lines so you get the endpoints coordinates. But, word to the wise, if you are doing lightsaber effects, you don't need to go that far - just paint the stick orange and do a chroma key. Standard feature of Adobe Premiere, Final Cut Pro, Sony Vegas, etc. The OpenCV version of this is to convert your frame to HSV color mode, and isolate regions of the picture that lie in your desired hue and saturation region.

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html?highlight=hough

Here is an old routine I wrote as an example:

```
//Photoshop-style color range selection with hue and saturation parameters.
//Expects input image to be in Hue-Lightness-Saturation colorspace.
//Returns a binary mask image. Hue and saturation bounds expect values from 0 to 255.
IplImage* selectColorRange(IplImage *image, double lowerHueBound, double upperHueBound, 
                double lowerSaturationBound, double upperSaturationBound) {
    cvSetImageCOI(image, 1);  //select hue channel
    IplImage* hue1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCopy(image, hue1); //copy hue channel to hue1
    cvFlip(hue1, hue1); //vertical-flip
    IplImage* hue2 = cvCloneImage(hue1); //clone hue image
    cvThreshold(hue1, hue1, lowerHueBound, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY); //threshold lower bound
    cvThreshold(hue2, hue2, upperHueBound, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV); //threshold inverse upper bound
    cvAnd(hue1, hue2, hue1); //intersect the threshold pair, save into hue1
    cvSetImageCOI(image, 3); //select saturation channel
    IplImage* saturation1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    cvCopy(image, saturation1); //copy saturation channel to saturation1
    cvFlip(saturation1, saturation1); //vertical-flip
    IplImage* saturation2 = cvCloneImage(saturation1); //clone saturation image
    cvThreshold(saturation1, saturation1, lowerSaturationBound, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY); //threshold lower bound
    cvThreshold(saturation2, saturation2, upperSaturationBound, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV); //threshold inverse upper bound
    cvAnd(saturation1, saturation2, saturation1); //intersect the threshold pair, save into saturation1
    cvAnd(saturation1, hue1, hue1); //intersect the matched hue and matched saturation regions
    cvReleaseImage(&saturation1);
    cvReleaseImage(&saturation2);
    cvReleaseImage(&hue2);
    return hue1;
}
```

A little verbose, but you get the idea!

Comment: should I use a blob tracker to get the length of my stick? or are there other ways to get the starting point and end point of my stick? thanks!

Comment: You can `findContours` of your binary image. Find the largest `contour` with `contourArea` and then use `minAreaRect` to obtain a `RotatedRect`, a bounding shape around the `contour`.  The height of the `RotatedRect` will be your stick length.

Comment: I've used the findContours and I think the rectangle created is not that stable especially when the object is moving. Then I used the Hough Transform CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC and it did the job. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by following the face-recognition (training & detection) techniques written for OpenCV.

If you are looking for specific steps, let me know.

Comment: Hmm... not sure how much that applies to tracking a stick.

Comment: Hi Matt, think like : A stick, normally imagined as a cylindrical object. A cylinder that can be in any position in 3D space. There are cases where we can detect and track similar cylindrical objects like a pen! Again, the distinctive features on such objects always helps in improving the detection/tracking. So, you might have to point of classify the distinctive features on this 'stick'. A sample image of such an object, both negative and positive will certainly help me to improve my suggestions to you.

Comment: Someone, I guess you added the Hough transform code to detect the stick! But one had to consider the orientation of any object. Occlusion is another aspect. Lowe's paper can help in this regards.

Answer (score 2):

My old professor always said that the first law of computer vision is to do whatever you can to the image to make your job easier.

If you have control over the stick's appearance, then you might have the best luck painting the stick a very specific color --- neon pink or something that isn't likely to appear in the background --- and then using color segmentation combined with connected component labeling.  That would be very fast.